# Create a field in select with case statement

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm trying to create a field that is populated with a case statement but I don't think it's working.

```
select 
    case when NVL(rule_id,'') <> '' then 'n' 
    when NVL(rule_id_2, '') <> '' then 'p' else
end as type
```

I want to add these fields into my result set.

Comment: Whats not working about it? And if you can shown some sample data and some expected data people will understand better what you are trying to do.

Comment: You need a value between `else` and `end` too.

Answer (score 0):

Use [coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014) (or [isnull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014))

```
select 
    case
      when coalesce(rule_id,'') <> '' then 'n' 
      when coalesce(rule_id_2, '') <> '' then 'p'
      else ''
end as type
```

If your intent is for type to have N if rule_id is not null and P if rule_id_2 is not null then you could use something like this:

```
select
    case
      when rule_id is not null then 'n'
      when rule_id_2 is not null then 'p'
      else ''
    end as tpye
```